# Copy/Paste menu items aren't shown on some devices in Android EditText

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, long-click

I have a subclass of Android EditText and it' declared as:

```
    ...
    android:id="@+id/Main.editor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    ...
```

On most devices user are able to do a long click and see a menu with Copy/Paste items:

In emulator:

[image]

On device (where it works):

[image]

However on some devices it's not shown on long click:

[image]

What can be a reason?
I'm thinking about declaring `android:longClickable="true"` explicitly but i believe it's a default value.

UPDATE: It's reproducible on some Android 9 devices, so it seems to be not that issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65575880

Comment: have you solved the issue? I also have a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67777875/android-edit-text-there-is-no-paste-option could you please help, if you have solved it already?

Comment: Do you still encounter the same issue recently?

Answer (score 0):

Android has a default feature to show copy/paste menu

Try with this in your xml [android:textIsSelectable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textIsSelectable).

i.e., `android:textIsSelectable="true"`

Comment: are there any reasons to do it explicitly? Originally `textIsSelectable` relates to `TextView` which does not have selectable behaviour in contrast to `EditText`

Comment: using the `android:textIsSelectable="true"` on `EditText` will not open the Keyboard on clicking on `EditText`.